# How to create a form for comments with the ability of dynamically adding them to the list?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a form for comments with the ability to dynamically add them to the list. Each comment should have an assigned ID in consecutive order. The newest comment should be at the very bottom. Comments should be stored in the comments array. Each comment should have properties such as id (number) and text (string). Comments array must be empty when loaded initially. Each click on the "Add" button should create a new object inside the array and create element in the DOM tree.

```js
let nextId = 1;

const comments = [];

const commentForm = document.querySelector('[data-id="comment-form"]');
const commentInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="comment"]');
const button = commentForm.querySelector('[data-action="add"]');
const commentList = commentForm.querySelector('[data-id="comment-list"]');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const object = {};
  if (commentInput.value != '') {
    comments.map(() => ({ id: 'nextId++', text: commentInput.value }));
  }
  createElement();
});

function createElement() {
  const newComment = document.createElement('li');
  newComment.setAttribute('data-comment-id', comments.id);
  newComment.textContent = comments.text;
  commentList.appendChild(newComment);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <form data-id="comment-form">
        <textarea data-input="comment"></textarea>
        <button data-action="add">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul data-id="comment-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

1. You are trying to access *commentList* from *commentForm*, but that element is outside of the *commentForm*. Use *document* object to access the element.
2. *comments* is an array from which you are trying to access *text* property, there is *text* property on *comments*.
3. You should pass the current input value to the function so that you can set the newly created *LI*'s text with the value.
4. You should use `push()` instead of `map()` to push an item into the array. `nextId` is a variable but you are using that as if it is a string, you should remove the quotes around it.
5. For the better user experience, I will suggest you to clear the value of the input after creating the item.

**Demo:**

```js
let nextId = 1;

const comments = [];

const commentForm = document.querySelector('[data-id="comment-form"]');
const commentInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="comment"]');
const button = commentForm.querySelector('[data-action="add"]');
const commentList = document.querySelector('[data-id="comment-list"]');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const object = {};
  if (commentInput.value != '') {
    comments.push({ id: nextId++, text: commentInput.value });
  }
  createElement(commentInput.value);
  commentInput.value = '';
});

function createElement(ci) {
  const newComment = document.createElement('li');
  newComment.setAttribute('data-comment-id', comments.id);
  newComment.textContent = ci;
  commentList.appendChild(newComment);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <form data-id="comment-form">
        <textarea data-input="comment"></textarea>
        <button type="button" data-action="add">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul data-id="comment-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```